# Hive: Finding the latest date in hive table using partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition

I have a big hive table with almost million records partitioned by date.
I want to find the latest date based off the last partition added to the hive table. 
There is a probability that some days, or weeks, there might be no record. So I cannot use current_date or current_date - 1 to find the last date. I also tried max(ingest_date) but it took almost 140 minutes to find the date.

Here's a sample partition:

```
ingest_date=2019-6-10
ingest_date=2019-6-7
ingest_date=2019-6-6
ingest_date=2019-6-5
ingest_date=2019-6-4
```

Is there a better way to find the latest date in the hive table from the partitions without using MAX() function?

Comment: You can write a `shell script` to implement this.

Comment: This is how to do this using shell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952357/2700344